# Does lseek in C provide some modification in data structures?

Tags: c, unix, lseek

I know that open and close modify the OS general file table, process file table and inode table.
But what does lseek modify and how??

Comment: The position of the "cursor" where the stream is read from or written to by functions that take no explicit offset, provided the file is seekable.

Comment: Okay, but does this function modify something in those tables? Like I know that the index in the process file table is used to get the identifier for the the OS file table which has a pointer that points to the inode table and those contain Reference counts and Link counts. But does lseek modify something clear in those structures or is it something just related to the file and does not affect those tables?